# Fine tuned Resnet-50 model only gives 40% Accuracy. How to improve?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I thought that pre-built models were supposed to be high of accuracy simply by changing the last layer to accommodate your CNN needs. I am unsure of why I receive such a low validated accuracy when fitting the model. Any layer suggestions or what I should do to get my accuracy to 80%? I am attempting to decide whether a plane is an Airbus or a Boeing aircraft. Could it be the extremely low resolution image sizes?

40% Fitted Example:

```
Epoch 10/10

 20/149 [===>..........................] - ETA: 24s - loss: 0.6908 - accuracy: 0.5500
 40/149 [=======>......................] - ETA: 21s - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 0.5250
 60/149 [===========>..................] - ETA: 17s - loss: 0.6918 - accuracy: 0.5167
 80/149 [===============>..............] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.6917 - accuracy: 0.5125
100/149 [===================>..........] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.6918 - accuracy: 0.5200 
120/149 [=======================>......] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6924 - accuracy: 0.5167
140/149 [===========================>..] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6924 - accuracy: 0.5071
149/149 [==============================] - 33s 225ms/step - loss: 0.6925 - accuracy: 0.5034 - val_loss: 0.6965 - val_accuracy: 0.4706
```

Here is the full script:
Any idea of what is going wrong?

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.applications import VGG19
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import matplotlib as plt
import cv2
import os

'''Resnet-50 classifier that attempts to predict whether a photo of an aircraft is the type of a Boeing or an airbus'''

boeing_dir = '#' # Paths of images/folders used to create training data
airbus_dir = '#'

conv_base = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))




model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.15))
model.add(layers.GaussianNoise(0.15))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.layers[0].trainable = False
print('model constructed')
boeing_data = []
boeing_label = []
airbus_data = []
airbus_label = []
'''iterate through each file, resize, append to variable accordingly'''
for filename in os.listdir(boeing_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpeg"):
        path_b = os.path.join(boeing_dir, filename)
        im = cv2.imread(path_b)
        im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        im = cv2.resize(im, (224, 224))
        boeing_data.append(im)
        boeing_label.append(0)

for filename in os.listdir(airbus_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpeg"):
        path_b = os.path.join(airbus_dir, filename)
        im = cv2.imread(path_b)
        im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        im = cv2.resize(im, (224, 224))
        airbus_data.append(im)
        airbus_label.append(1)




training_data = boeing_data + airbus_data #Concadenate Boeing and Airbus data
training_label = boeing_label + airbus_label

training_data = np.array(training_data)
training_label = np.asarray(training_label) # Turn Data into numpy arrays
training_data, training_label = shuffle(training_data, training_label) # Shuffle

print(training_data.shape)
print(training_label)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_data, training_label, epochs=10, batch_size=20, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
print('finished training')
```

Comment: Have you tried without the layer having 64 nodes just before output layer? You also should try after making at least few deeper layers of resnet model as trainable to adapt with your task.

Comment: It did not make a difference. I removed my dropout and 64 neuron dense layer, however still got about the same. Maybe its that the resolution (224, 244) of the image is too bad to recognize anything. What shall I do?

Comment: Image size `(224, 224, 3)` is fine. You can try after making resnet50 model trainable by setting `layer.trainable = True` (or removing) so that backbone model also learns to adapt with your custom dataset and remove dense layer having 64 neurons as well. You also apply augmentation techniques (e.g. flip, flop, rotattion, adding gaussion noise...) on your data.

Comment: I did this, however it takes a lot of time per epoch and upgraded the accuracy about 10%.

Comment: How do I apply the flipping and rotation techniques?

Comment: You can check out Keras official documentation on `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory` [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). Also when you train full model instead of just last layer then it will take time and you should try with more epoch.

Comment: but why would you give your dense Layer(except the last one) a softmax activation?,sotmax will limit the values from 0 to 1,you need atleast Relus in the previous Dense Layers except the last Dense Layer

Comment: I will reiterate what @Eliethesaiyan said. You can't add Dense layer with `softmax` activation except output layer and GaussionNoise layer in the model without any justification.

Comment: My bad, when I was editing my post I accidentally got softmax in there, but even without it I get about the same accuracy.

Comment: The validation accuracy is random everytime I run it. Sometimes its 60% sometimes in 40%.

Comment: remove the GaussianNoiseLayer , it would have been only useful inside Resnet,(note that Resnet does features extraction for you),use one Dense layer with softmax

Comment: I changed it to have only one softmax dense layer and the resnet layer is non-trainable, however still getting 50% validation